# Python idiot moment: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to load a list of sentences into Python from a text file.

```
input_file = open('goods.txt', 'r')
goods = input_file.readlines()

print('# of goods:', len(goods))
for goodies in goods[:5]:
    print(goodies["text"])
```

The output I get is:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why `goodies["text"]` and not simply `goodies` ?

Comment: What is `goodies["text"]` supposed to be? Did you expect `goodies` to be a dict somehow?

Comment: `file.readlines()` returns a list of strings, then you try to access `file.readlines()[0]['text']`.

Comment: what is in your file and what are you trying to extract?

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is get a text file of lines into an array so that I can clean it up iteratively, removing stop words, etc. later on.

Comment: Adding some example lines and what you want as final output will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`goods` is a list, not a dict. You can not index a list with a string.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines):

> **file.readlines([sizehint])**
>
> Read until EOF using readline() and return a list containing the lines thus read. If the optional sizehint argument is present, instead of reading up to EOF, whole lines totalling approximately sizehint bytes (possibly after rounding up to an internal buffer size) are read. Objects implementing a file-like interface may choose to ignore sizehint if it cannot be implemented, or cannot be implemented efficiently.

Your code should look something like this:

```py
file = open('goods.txt', 'r')
goods = file.readlines()

print('# of goods:', len(goods))
for i, goodies in enumerate(goods):
    print(goodies)  # same as print(goods[i])
    # example of string manipulation
    goods[i] = goods[i].strip()
```

Each item in `goods` is a string with a line from `goods.txt`. This will print each line in that file, one at a time.

Adding `[:5]` in the `for` loop will iterate only over the first five lines of your file, if that is what you want.

Comment: A dict requires a unique key to each value. For example, this dict has one item, which value is a list of strings: `d = {'key': ['v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e']}`. What is your expected output? What do you want as a key for each item in your dict?

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is get a text file of lines into an array so that I can clean it up iteratively, removing stop words, etc. later on.

Comment: I should add that I'm a PHP guy who inherited some Python code, hence my idiotic questions.

Comment: For that purpose a list of strings seems a better fit than a dict. Just replace `print(goodies)` by any string manipulation method. Don't forget to save the result. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful. The code I inherited has this in a few instances, so next step will be to learn Python...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `goodies` like a dictionary, but apparently this is not the case.
Print `goodies` without `["text"]` to see if it's what you want.

Answer (score -1):

goods is a list, not a dict. You can not index a list with a string.

Comment: This has already been ascertained in the two answers supplied.

Comment: then what ? can't i answerr it too why SO is so harsh

Comment: Are you  asking why adding a poor answer that only contains  information that is already included in two other earlier answers is getting a downvote?

Comment: means you are also saying that other 2 answers are also poor